# Apache reverse proxy with self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I run a Unifi hardware appliance which comes with a self-signed certificate, issued on `unifi.local`. For my current setup, it's not an option to import a certificate on the appliance directly for several reasons, so I tried to get rid of the invalid certificate message of my browser by using an apache2-based reverse proxy which provides access to the appliance under another domain, secured by a Letsencrypt certificate.

My current setup looks like the following:

```
Laptop <-> Apache Reverse Proxy (2.4.48, Debian, trusted wildcard domain certificate) <-> Unifi appliance (self-signed certificate)
```

My idea is to provide a secured domain called `unifi.mydomain.tld` which allows secure access to the appliance.

In my apache reverse proxy, I created and enabled a config file which looks like following:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Serveradmin root@home.lan"
    ServerName unifi.mydomain.tld

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    ProxyPass "/" "https://10.0.1.1/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://10.0.1.1/"
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/proxies/unifi_access.log
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/proxies/unifi_error.log

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    </IfModule>

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite SSL ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
    SSLCipherSuite TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters /mnt/certificates/diffie-hellman/dhparam4096.pem
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCompression off
    SSLSessionTickets off

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tld/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tld/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

# Originally from /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
# Written directly here because otherwise SSLProtocol etc is overwritten
# Add vhost name to log entries:
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

</IfModule>
```

However, if I access `unifi.mydomain.tld`, my browser returns the certificate for `unifi.local` and not for `unifi.mydomain.tld` and hence, it creates an error that the certificate is not trusted. Several tips mentioned to turn `SSLProxyVerify` to `none`, and `SSLProxyCheckPeerName`, `SSLProxyCheckPeerCN`, and `SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire` to `off`, however, none of these tricks worked. It's not an option for me to import Unifi's self-signed snakeoil certificate on my reverse proxy server.

I'm not sure whether apache2 itself complains about the certificate or returns the wrong certificate. How am I able to get access to the appliance by browsing `unifi.mydomain.tld` without getting this certificate error?

Comment: It's not apache, almost certainly your browser is connecting to the Unifi NOT apache as you wish. Check the name resolution for unifi.mydomain.tld used by the browser. I say 'name resolution' not specifically DNS; name resolution _often_ uses DNS but it can use numerous other methods. If in doubt, try getting a network capture (wireshark, tcpdump, or similar) showing the browser connection(s) and particularly the IP address and MAC address it connects to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me!

Requirements:

1. Apache Tomcat on :8443 with self-signed key
2. Apache HTTPD with Reverse Proxy to localhost:8443 Tomcat
3. Apache HTTPD *REQUIRES* Client Mutual Authentication. If that is not a requirement for you, then set:  SSLVerifyClient none
4. Apache HTTPD will pass along the X.509 identity of the caller through the reverse proxy to tomcat.

---

```
 ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
 TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
 LogLevel warn
 ProxyRequests On
 ProxyPass /test1 https://localhost:8443/test/
 ProxyPassReverse /test1 https://localhost:8443/test/
# SSL Settings for the DMZ
 SSLEngine on
 SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
 SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/jdoyle/sample_httpd_server_example_root_ca_.key
 SSLCertificateFile /home/jdoyle/sample_httpd_server_example_root_ca_.cer
 SSLCACertificateFile /home/jdoyle/consolidated_cacerts.cer
# SSL Settings for the Reverse Proxy
 SSLProxyEngine on
 SSLProxyVerify require
 SSLProxyProtocol TLSv1.2
 SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
 SSLProxyCACertificateFile /home/jdoyle/consolidated_cacerts.cer
 SSLVerifyClient require
 SSLVerifyDepth  10
# Pass the SSL Conext on to tomcat

RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_I_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU "%{SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_V_START "%{SSL_CLIENT_V_START}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_V_END "%{SSL_CLIENT_V_END}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_M_VERSION "%{SSL_CLIENT_M_VERSION}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL "%{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION "%{SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_I_DN "%{SSL_SERVER_I_DN}s"
....

SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
....
```

---

Notes:

a. SSLProxyCACertificateFile is for the httpd<->tomcat connection and  contains the Public Key of the Tomcat Server's self-signed cert.

b. SSLCACertificateFile is for the DMZ <-> httpd connection, and must contain and and all of the CA Certs for any inbound connection.

Comment: Thanks, hoped that I do not need to install additional software like Tomcat, however this works.